# is there a way to recursively merge then rebase all branches?

Tags: git, merge, git-rebase

Let's say I have git repo like this:

```
master
webapp-1252
webapp-1285
webapp-1384
webapp-1433
webapp-1524
webapp-824
x_____jira_
x_webapp-11
x_webapp-11
x_webapp-11
z_____jira_
```

I've updated all of them and ready to push them all to svn or something. Then someone makes a quick change that would require me to basically go through all of them to merge etc.

Is there a shortcut to go through all the branches I have here, merge them with whatever work that was fetched, then rebase them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See those answers for solutions of similar problems:

- [Rebasing a branch including all its children](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5600659/rebasing-a-branch-including-all-its-children)
- [Git: How to rebase many branches (with the same base commit) at once?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/866218/git-how-to-rebase-many-branches-with-the-same-base-commit-at-once)

I believe both of them can be used to solve Your problem.