# git workflow branch / clone / stash / --orphan

Tags: git, git-branch, git-rebase, git-clone, git-workflow

I've recently dived into Git and maybe I'm over complicating this but I'm trying to figure out the best workflow for the following:

I have created a 'backbone' or 'base' of sorts for themes similar to 'bootstrap' grid based system, responsive etc. I want to keep that base across all themes and have files ontop that I modify from theme to theme. When the time comes to update the base I update across all themes, without affecting the theme files ontop.

eg.
theme.css   <-- Will change from theme to theme
theme.js    <-- Will change from theme to theme
[base]        <-- Files that will be used across all themes

What's the best way to do this with git? Do I have a single master repo and have multiple branches for the different themes that I'll never merge into the master?

Answer (score 1):

It is best to manage those themes in branches.

When the base change (on master), you can rebase all themes branches on master.
See "[Git: How to rebase many branches (with the same base commit) at once?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/866218/git-how-to-rebase-many-branches-with-the-same-base-commit-at-once)".