# rebase multiple feature branch

Tags: git, git-branch, git-detached-head

Me and my friends are collaborating a project (all amateurs) and we're having a hard time on git rebase. Our workflow is that we work on each of our own branches and every time someone finishes their work, they push it and send a pull request. After we review and give the PR the green light, we will rebase it to master. Sounds a very organized process but everytime we rebase a branch to master, it seems that if we want another branch to be rebased into master, we're now on a detached head. So any tips on how to avoid this detached head?

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in "[Git: How to rebase many branches (with the same base commit) at once?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/866353/6309)", there shouldn't be any detached HEAD.

Each rebase would replay the branch and re-create a HEAD for each rebased branch.

Rebasing a branch *and* its children is a bit trickier: see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5632027/6309).

Comment: Well I wish it does replay it. To be more precise, we're not doing the rebase at the same time. We rebase it 1 PR at a time, since the one that requested the PR is also the one in-charge of rebasing. So after he rebases and pushes his branch back to repo, we pull it and we try to rebase our own topic branches, and that's where the Detached Head happens. Any comment on this?

Comment: @Finks detached head shouldn't occur, since what a rebase does is to checkout the branch being rebased in order to replay commits of said branch on top of the specified target branch (`git rebase target`): if you are in a checked out branch when you do that rebase, you end up in that same (replayed) branch. With its HEAD intact.

Comment: Additional info and last question, we're actually in a staging branch first (i just noticed). So staging is a branch of master. And we're actually creating those feature branches off of the staging branch. Should there be a problem here? Sorry for being a pest, I understand what you're saying but our repo is still being detached everytime we rebase branches.