# Introduce changes from several branches through "chained rebase"

Tags: git, git-rebase

```
o----o----o----o----o-----o----o----o origin/master
          \          \I---F---J   branch 2
           \A--B--C    branch 1
```

My goal is to introduce features from `branch 1` into `branch 2` and make `branch2` up-to-date by rebasing on `origin/master`

What I'm doing is

```
checkout branch1
rebase origin/master
checkout branch2
rebase branch1
```

That's not too hard. But I thought that it would be so if I had many feature branches that I wanted to introduce changes from. Is there any better way to do such "chained rebases"?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Git: How to rebase many branches (with the same base commit) at once?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/866218/git-how-to-rebase-many-branches-with-the-same-base-commit-at-once)

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe there is a way to do a long chain of rebases all at once. But you can do a little bit better than you are doing. You don't need the `git checkout`s:

```
git rebase foo_branch bar_branch
```

is the same as

```
git checkout bar_branch
git rebase foo_branch
```